Electron app asks different permissions on Mac - local network devices, microphone
I have an electron app that is a small game publishing platform UI and just shows user some games related content. I've noticed that for some users my app asks permissions to find devices on local network, to access microphone etc., but I dont really use any kind of these features. How to troubleshoot these requests or disable them compeletely? I didn't find anything in my source code, and my dependencies are almost empty, there are only ws, electron-log and bindings.
